# Why isn't Google Chrome available in the Software Centre?

Tags: software-center, google-chrome

Google Chrome is available for Ubuntu on the Google website but why is it not present in Ubuntu Software Centre?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

#### Because Google Chrome contains *non-free* parts (internal PDF, Flash and media support)

As you may know, the *Chromium* browser is available in Ubuntu Software Center. Google Chrome is built from the *same source code* as Chromium, but includes some additional features which make it impossible to distribute via Software Center/the official repositories.

Specifically, it [includes proprietary PDF/Flash plugins as well as support for AAC/MP3/etc. formats](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/ChromiumBrowserVsGoogleChrome). These components are non-free (no source-code available), so Ubuntu's policy forbids distributing Chrome via the Software Center/repositories.

#### Chrome also requires agreement to a restrictive EULA (license)

Additionally, while Chromium/the source has a free license (BSD), Google requires you to agree to a much more restrictive ["End User License Agreement" (EULA)](https://www.google.com/chrome/eula.html) to download and use Chrome.

#### Google forbids third-parties from distributing Chrome

I believe Google also prohibits anyone (or any site) from redistributing the full Chrome; that's why the "portable Chrome" packages you find will download Chrome from Google when you install them, instead of including it. Even [Download.com](http://download.cnet.com/Google-Chrome/3001-2356_4-10881381.html) only gives you the tiny installer which downloads Chrome from the Google servers.

#### Solution: download it, or use Google's PPA

The solution if you must have Chrome, as the other answers have explained, is to download Chrome or install it via [Google's own PPA](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/google_chrome)

Answer (score 3):

In short, licensing issues.  You can install Google Chrome by visiting www.google.com or following this direct link to [Google Chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome/index.html?hl=en&brand=CHNG&utm_source=en-hpp&utm_medium=hpp&utm_campaign=en).

Answer (score 3):

Is only because of google. Being restrictive and having non-free parts are not the reasons. Ubuntu software center accepts free software and non-free software, like flash, Acrobat reader, skype, etc.

And btw, google does not have a ppa, they indeed have an apt repository which is not necesarilly a ppa.

Answer (score 1):

The repository has always had Chromium instead.  According to the information on this:

"Chromium serves as a base for Google Chrome, which is Chromium rebranded (name and logo) with very few additions such as usage tracking and an auto-updater system."

It looks the same, just a slightly different name.

Comment: The **auto-updater system** doesn't function in the Linux OS. Linux users get their "auto-updates" via the operating system's software update manager. And, each time it's a **full-sized** download whereas for MS Windows, the download, which is managed by Google's own updater, is often [differential](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711435/has-anybody-used-google-omaha-their-auto-update-engine-for-chrome) and smaller than a full download.

Answer (score 1):

If you're set on using Google Chrome instead of Chromium, then you can [use the PPA that Google provides](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/google_chrome).