# Installing Chrome correctly

Tags: software-center, google-chrome

I'm a longtime Windows user but I've been interested in Linux for quite some time as a possible alternative.  I've dabbled with it a number of times but just installed 15.04 GNOME as a dual boot with Windows 8.1 and definitely like what I see so far; it sure reminds me of my days as a Mac user.

Anyway, I'm quite comfortable with tinkering so I downloaded and installed Google Chrome (i.e. not Chromium) by grabbing the package from Google's website.  It installed and runs fine, but it doesn't show up in the Ubuntu Software Center's list of installed apps.  How can I get it to show up correctly?  If I ever need to uninstall it I'd like to be able to do so through the Software Center GUI.

Thanks,
Luke

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. You have installed Chrome correctly. During installation Chrome has added its private repository to the Ubuntu update management system's list of repositories. This means, from time to time you will see Chrome being updated along with other updates. Also see http://askubuntu.com/questions/163640/why-isnt-google-chrome-available-in-the-software-centre

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly new to Ubuntu aswell, but maybe this will help:

[Why isn't Google Chrome available in the Software Centre?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163640/why-isnt-google-chrome-available-in-the-software-centre)

Answer (score 0):

You can't see Chrome in Software Center, because you installed it not from Ubuntu repositories.

You can easily remove it from terminal by running

```
sudo dpkg -r google-chrome-stable
```

Or using Synaptic program. It is a GUI application.

Comment: If you search for `google chrome-stable` in **Ubuntu Software Center** you will see that it is installed. You can also go to the drop down list of Installed Software icon in **Ubuntu Software Center** and select **Google** and then see it there.